# Runtime Error '5852' Requested object is not available. Issue with .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

So I have been trying to use a the below macro to split a mail-merged document into individual documents. When I run the macro, I receive "Runtime Error '5852' Requested object is not available." The issue is highlighted as `.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument`when using the debug action.

I though that perhaps the issue was with the file being located on my OneDrive but after moving the files to a local drive, I recieved the same issue. Any insight into how to resolve this error would be helpful.

If more info is necessary, please let me know and I would be happy to answer as best I could.

Code for reference:

```
   Sub MailMergeToDoc()
'
' MailMergeToDoc Macro
' Collects the results of the mail merge in a document
'
' Sourced from: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, MainDoc As Document, i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
With MainDoc
  StrFolder = .Path & "\"
  With .MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("Last_Name")) = "" Then Exit For
        'StrFolder = .DataFields("Folder") & "\"
        StrName = .DataFields("Last_Name") & "_" & .DataFields("First_Name")
      End With
      On Error GoTo NextRecord
      .Execute Pause:=False
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = Trim(StrName)
      With ActiveDocument
        'Add the name to the footer
        '.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InsertBefore StrName
        .SaveAs FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        ' and/or:
        .SaveAs2 FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
NextRecord:
    Next i
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic troubleshooting. You can't just copy code without understanding what it's doing.

**Your MailMerge object does not exist** when you're trying to run the mail merge.

***You need to create a Mail Merge first*** in your Word doc - just use the Wizard - and that object will be magically filled. Then you'll have to progress to your next error.

Comment: That is what document I am working in. I ran a mail merge first and now am trying to execute the macro within the new mail merged doc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this resolved too, but not using your tip.  The problem was that even though I was saving my source docs to my desktop, my desktop was linked to company SharePoint (and Sharepoint was in my path).  Despite having the correct paths in the excel sheet it was Sharepoint that was messing things up.  I copied all of my data onto my personal machine (no worries, no PII here), updated the paths and bingo!  it worked.   I'm not a programmer (obviously), so this took several hours of going through every tip, every data, point multiple ways.   But still, saves me about 8 hours of renaming and filing these freakin documents!